# Can't find Variable: NavigationContainer

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I've been having a problem with NavigationContainer from react-navigation/native. I keep getting an error saying:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: NavigationContainer
```

I have `import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';` imported at the top but I still get the same error. I checked the package.json and it's installed. I have also uninstalled node_modules twice and I still have the same problem.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
```

Here is my app.js code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Screen from './app/components/Screen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';


const Tweets = () => (
  <Screen>
    <Text>Tweets</Text>
  </Screen>
);

const TweetDetails = () => (
  <Screen>
    <Text>Tweet Details</Text>
  </Screen>
);

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => (
  <StackNavigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Tweets" component={Tweets} />
    <Stack.Screen name="TweetDetails" component={TweetDetails} />
  </StackNavigator>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Please help me find the source of the problem, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why it would cause the error you're seeing, but the definition of `StackNavigator` looks like it's recursive. Is that intentional?

It looks like it should be `Stack.Navigator` instead of `StackNavigator`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, I guess I got it mixed up with the const StackNavigator lol.

Comment: Posted as answer, since it doesn't seem that a comment can be used to fully answer a question. (I'm new to answering questions on SO.)

Comment: That's alright, you deserve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block has `StackNavigator` as being recursive.

```js
const StackNavigator = () => (
  <StackNavigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Tweets" component={Tweets} />
    <Stack.Screen name="TweetDetails" component={TweetDetails} />
  </StackNavigator>
);
```

Changing the inner `StackNavigator` to `Stack.Navigator` should resolve the problem.

```js
const StackNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Tweets" component={Tweets} />
    <Stack.Screen name="TweetDetails" component={TweetDetails} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```